# Will angels surround you if you read Quran but have a dog as an indoor pet?

Tags: quran, malaikah, dogs

Having a dog indoor is haram because angels won’t come to your house. But when you read Quran angels surround you because they can’t read. These aren’t mutually exclusive however.